# How to return a value from Windows Form

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I created a windows forms application named Project08. It has the files *Form1.h*, *Form2.h* and *Project08.cpp* with some other files. My usage scenario in short is this:

- When program starts Form1 is displayed.
- User enters his/her name and clicks a button.
- When the button is clicked, Form1 closes and user's name is returned to where the Form1 is called from.
- The return value is assigned to a string.
- Form2 is called, and displayed.

How can I return the user's name to Project08.cpp? My Project08.cpp is below. Is my code below a good way of doing this? If not can you recommend another way?

```
// Project08.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include "Form2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace Project08;

[STAThreadAttribute] int main(array<System::String ^> ^args) {
// Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

// Create the main window and run it
Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
// assign user's name to a string here
Application::Run(gcnew Form2());
return 0; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right you have some kind of Text Field in Form1 in which a user enters his/her name. And you need to return that value back to the function that calls `Application::Run(Form^)`

To accomplish this I would not create an instance of Form1 anonymously. I would make a pointer / reference to it so that I have access to it after its construction.

```
Form1^ form1 = gcnew Form1();
Application::Run(form1);
```

Then you need to do some stuff in your Form1 class. First you need to save the Text of your Input Field when you click on that Button, because the Form will invalidate all components on Dispose. Add a click handler on the button click event to save the Text of your input component (in this example a TextBox) in a Class Member Variable:

```
class Form1 [...]
{
    [...]
private:
    System::String^ m_Name; // Create a member variable for the value
    [...]
}

// Add a click Handler for your Button (do this in the Designer) and save the Text of the Text Box in it
System::Void Form1::button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    m_Name = textBoxName->Text;
}
```

Then I would add a getter Method for the saved value that you can later call by your main Method:

```
System::String^ Form1::getUsername()
{
    return this->m_Name; // return the last saved Text of your Input control
}
```

`Application::Run()` stops the executing thread as long as the Form displays, so in your Project08.cpp file you would have:

```
[...]
Form1^ form1 = gcnew Form1(); // Create the instance and keep a pointer to it
Application::Run(form1); // Display the Form
System::String^ name = form1->getUsername(); // Get the saved Name after the Form disposed
// Do stuff with the name in Form 2
Application:Run(gcnew Form2(name));
[...]
```

Comment: You understand all correct, thanks a lot. But I get this error with the getter Method: error C3149: 'System::String' : cannot use this type here without a top-level '^'

Comment: @Engin I'm sorry I forgot to put '^' after System::String. Haven't programmed CLI in C++ for a while ;p. I updated my answer

Comment: @Engin you're welcome. You might want to consider accepting this as answer if it solved your problem. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.